# Copy the first word of the filename

Tags: bash, shell, filenames

```
 zBase=$(basename "{query}")
title=${zBase%.*}
echo -n $title;
```

The above command copies the filename to the clipboard (using Alfred: the {query} part is from Alfred). Now, I want to copy only the first word of the filename. How can I modify it?

Here is an example filename:

John 2015 Noun and verb structure.pdf

The above commend gives me [John 2015 Noun and verb structure] in my clipboard. Now, I want to get only **John** in my clipboard.

Comment: “The above commend gives me [John 2015 Noun and verb structure] in my clipboard.” — no it does not, in so many ways it does not. It look like you were working to two things at once, and put them both into this question, as I see no relation ship between the code above and this statement.

Comment: when you define zBase you could take the output of the `basename` and pipe it through `cut` using the `-d` option (delimiter) and specify a space as the delimiter  - see this for an example - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4d2d7261588a69fc7779511d3e50e3d6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using external tools like `sed`, `cut` or `awk`, you can simply use the shell's build-in variable expansion that you already used for removing the extension:

```
echo -n ${title%% *}
```

Using double `%%` means remove the longest match, so you remove everything from the variable starting with the first whitespace.

Comment: Wow, that is great. It worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
title=$(echo $title | cut -d" " -f1)
```

Add this before echo. It cut's the name at every space and takes the first part -> What you wanted to do

Comment: thank you. Yes, this also worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go,
`title=$(echo $zBase|awk {'print $1'})`

In awk $1 gives the first word, $2 2nd word and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can always rely on any text processing tool to do the job. Say `sed` for instance:

```
$ sed -r 's/^([[:alpha:]]*).*/\1/' <<< "John 2015 Noun and verb structure.pdf"
John
```